# Using Optimization algorithm for white matter fiber tracking

Tags: matlab

Actually I use MATLAB code to implement my work which it's summarize as a following:
I used a program applied the Bayesian approach to solve fiber tracking, I have a problem in load  the dataset, which it's Medical Image. I need any hint to help me to open this data set to continue my work.  the following code shows the load dataset function:

```
function data = Load_DMRI_Data(dataset)
```

% Load diffusion tensor MRI data and return it in
% a structure together with gradients and b-values.
% The data must be stored in a data structure for further
% processing, see code.
% The gradients are stored as a(3xg) matrix, where g is the
% number of acquired DWI volumens (including the b=0 ones).
% The b-values are stored in a corresponding (1xg) vector.

if strcmp(dataset,'gordon')

```
readdir = '/projects/lmi/data/diffusion/gk-3t/041020-02156-bvalexpr/data/003/';
intensity = zeros(256,256,31,32);
for g = 1:32
    for slice = 1:31

        fid = fopen(sprintf('%sI.%03d',readdir,(g-1)*31+slice),'r');
        im = fread(fid,'int16');
        im = im(end-256^2+1:end);
        intensity(:,:,slice,g) = reshape(im,[256 256])';
        fclose(fid);
    end
end
G = load('gradients.mat');
G = [[1;1;1] G.g];   % Add arbitrary gradient direction for b=0
b = [0 1000*ones(1,31)];
data = struct('intensity',intensity,'G',G,'b',b,'FOV',240,'SliceThickness',4);
```

elseif strcmp(dataset,'pc')
    readdir = 'c:\Work\DiffusionData\';
    intensity = zeros(256,256,1,32);
    for g = 1:32
        for slice = 16:16             % Use slice 16 as test slice
            fid = fopen(sprintf('%sI.%03d',readdir,(g-1)*31+slice),'r','ieee-be');
            im = fread(fid,'int16');
            im = im(end-256^2+1:end);

```
        intensity(:,:,slice-15,g) = reshape(im,[256 256])';
        fclose(fid);
    end
end


G = load(sprintf('%sgradients.mat',readdir));
G = [[1;1;1] G.g];   % Add arbitrary gradient direction for b=0
b = [0 1000*ones(1,31)];  % b-values
data = struct('intensity',intensity,'G',G,'b',b);
```

end

The website for dataset : http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gk/DTI-data/